# Avoid warning: '"cc" clobber ignored' with PGI on RUNNING_ON_VALGRIND?

Tags: pgi

We get warnings of the type

```
"/var/lib/buildbot/slaves/athor-linux-pgi-c-nompi/petsc/src/sys/objects/pinit.c
         ", line 1493: warning: "cc" clobber ignored
   if (!(RUNNING_ON_VALGRIND)) {
```

When compiling with the latest community version of the NVIDIA/PGI C compiler.

We like to compile with all warning flags on so don't want to turn off warning flags if possible.

RUNNING_ON_VALGRIND is defined in valgrind.h to eventually become a use of

```
#define __SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_PREAMBLE                            \
                     "roll $3,  %%edi ; roll $13, %%edi\n\t"      \
                     "roll $29, %%edi ; roll $19, %%edi\n\t"

#define VALGRIND_DO_CLIENT_REQUEST_EXPR(                          \
        _zzq_default, _zzq_request,                               \
        _zzq_arg1, _zzq_arg2, _zzq_arg3, _zzq_arg4, _zzq_arg5)    \
  __extension__                                                   \
  ({volatile unsigned int _zzq_args[6];                           \
    volatile unsigned int _zzq_result;                            \
    _zzq_args[0] = (unsigned int)(_zzq_request);                  \
    _zzq_args[1] = (unsigned int)(_zzq_arg1);                     \
    _zzq_args[2] = (unsigned int)(_zzq_arg2);                     \
    _zzq_args[3] = (unsigned int)(_zzq_arg3);                     \
    _zzq_args[4] = (unsigned int)(_zzq_arg4);                     \
    _zzq_args[5] = (unsigned int)(_zzq_arg5);                     \
    __asm__ volatile(__SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_PREAMBLE               \
                     /* %EDX = client_request ( %EAX ) */         \
                     "xchgl %%ebx,%%ebx"                          \
                     : "=d" (_zzq_result)                         \
                     : "a" (&_zzq_args[0]), "0" (_zzq_default)    \
                     : "cc", "memory"                             \
                    );                                            \
    _zzq_result;                                                  \
  })
```

Is there any way to avoid the clobber message?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to ignore warnings (i.e. add the "-w" flag), or do you want to fix the code so the warning doesn't occur?  "cc" clobber is would most likely be coming from an ASM statement so it would be good to know what "RUNNING_ON_VALGRID" is defined as.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: I sent this to our engineers.  Basically, the warning is extraneous so they'll look at disabling in the compiler.  I've added an issue report, TPR#29277, to track.

Comment: Great, thanks, this is helpful.

Comment: This issue might be related (happens with nvhpc 20.11 too): https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/3020

Comment: Apologies for not updating earlier, but TPR #29277 was fixed in NVHPC SDK release 21.3